# Upload multiple images with titles and descriptions

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload multiple images into a gallery page but each image has to have a title and a description. Also each image needs to be resized.

I can currently upload one image with the title and description like this:

```
//create gallery folder and image resize code above^^

move_uploaded_file($temp, $path);


$title          =   Input::get('title');
$file_name      =   $file_name;
$added          =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$description    =   Input::get('description');

$insertdata = DB::getInstance()->insert('gallery', array(
    'added'         => $added,
    'title'         => $title,
    'description'   => $description,
    'file_name'     => str_replace("../images/gallery/", "", $file_name),
));

//Error Checking and Success Message etc...
if(!$insertdata)
```

**My Current Form**

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Title*:<br />
        <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="60" placeholder="Give this field a title" required>
        <br><br>

        Image Description*:<br />
        <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="8" placeholder="Pop in some details" required></textarea>
        <br><br>


        Add an image:<br />
        <input type="file" name="image" >
        <p id="size">Maximum file size of 5MB</p>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Image">
</form>
```

I'm just not sure what I need to add to allow this form to upload both images and data into my table.

When I try the below form it only uploads the last entry into the table and skips the first entry.

**What I would like to do with my form:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Title*:<br />
        <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="60" placeholder="Give this field a title" required>
        <br><br>

        Image Description*:<br />
        <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="8" placeholder="Pop in some details" required></textarea>
        <br><br>


        Add an image:<br />
        <input type="file" name="image" >
        <p id="size">Maximum file size of 5MB</p>

        <br><br><br><br>

        Title*:<br />
        <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="60" placeholder="Give this field a title" required>
        <br><br>

        Image Description*:<br />
        <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="8" placeholder="Pop in some details" required></textarea>
        <br><br>


        Add an image:<br />
        <input type="file" name="image" >
        <p id="size">Maximum file size of 5MB</p>


    <input type="submit" value="Add Image">
</form>
```

Any suggestions or help with this would be much appreciated.

Here is the full code to this script. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nfLXHg8w)

This code allows me to insert the text fields into the table even if there isn't an image present.

That's why there is the if  / else statement at the top.

Comment: Try adding `[]` to the `name` attributes.  `<input type="file" name="image[]" >` (as well as the `name` attributes of the other fields).  That will make then submit as arrays.  `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)` to see what you are getting.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I get the following warnings:>>>>

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in on line 72 |||||

Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given on line 72 |||||

Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 73 |||||

line 72
`$ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $name)));` |||||

line 73 `$size2 = getimagesize($temp);`

Comment: HAve you tried to `var_dump($name)` to see what's in it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When uploading multiple files you will need to loop through the files:

```
<?php

function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

?>
```

`reArrayFiles()` is meant to reorganize the data structure

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';


if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_POST)) {
    $files = reArrayFiles($_FILES['image']);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $temp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $path = 'upload/'.$file['name'];//replace
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $path)){
            $insertdata = DB::getInstance()->insert('gallery', array(
                'added' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'title'=> $_POST['title'][$i],
                'description'=> $_POST['description'][$i],
                'file_name'  => $path,                                              
            ));
        }else{
            echo 'failed to upload';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}else{
    echo 'file not uploaded';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append `[]` to your input element names.  This make them submit as arrays.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Title*:<br />
        <input type="text" name="title[]" maxlength="60" placeholder="Give this field a title" required>
        <br><br>

        Image Description*:<br />
        <textarea id="description" name="description[]" rows="8" placeholder="Pop in some details" required></textarea>
        <br><br>


        Add an image:<br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" >
        <p id="size">Maximum file size of 5MB</p>

        <br><br><br><br>

        Title*:<br />
        <input type="text" name="title[]" maxlength="60" placeholder="Give this field a title" required>
        <br><br>

        Image Description*:<br />
        <textarea id="description" name="description[]" rows="8" placeholder="Pop in some details" required></textarea>
        <br><br>


        Add an image:<br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" >
        <p id="size">Maximum file size of 5MB</p>


    <input type="submit" value="Add Image">
</form>
```

Doing this will make `$_POST['title']` and `$_POST['description']` into arrays.

As for `$_FILES`, it will be a bit different.  `$_FILES['image']` will still have `name`, `type`, etc. values, but they will be arrays.  For example `$_FILES['image']['name']` will be an array of all uploaded file names.  The same will be true for everything else in `$_FILES['image']`.